# Flutter and Angular Dart both share the component pattern, but what is the one fundamental difference between the two frameworks?

Tags: flutter, dart, angular-dart

A simple answer will suffice. I'm looking to build a new website and I like the expandability and code sharing happening in the Dart frameworks, but I don't really understand how the two frameworks differ on a fundamental level. The answer can be as in-depth as you like, but I'm really just looking for the layman answer.

Comment: Very valid question. Don't understand why it is closed. See people's discussions: https://www.reddit.com/r/dartlang/comments/btqm3d/angulardart_or_flutter_web/ or https://medium.com/flutter-community/hummingbird-vs-angular-dart-b636b7147099

Comment: This question should be reopened as I am very satisfied with the answer I received from @Remi Rousselet. I didn't know that it was a methodological difference and I didn't know the two used different patterns. If you look at his answer, we continue to the inquiry. This helped clear up the difference for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AngularDart is, well, Angular in Dart.

Flutter, on the other hand, is a lot closer to React.

Flutter uses the Component pattern from React but is manipulated without HTML/CSS, and instead uses canvas/custom elements.

Comment: Is "Angular" a programming concept or development pattern?

Comment: It's a web UI framework based on template files

Comment: Ah, so you are saying the main similarity between Angular frameworks (dart, javascript, etc) is that they use "template files." On a search, https://angulardart.dev/guide/template-syntax, I see a focus on "components" in angular programming as well. If this is the case, Flutter and Angular Dart share the component pattern, no?

Comment: Yes. Angular (JS and Dart) is basically like html files, but composable and with dynamic content.